# Assigning child without parent

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to declare a global variable in a module, which is done using object `window`, but when I declare directly a child of a child like this: `window.parent.child = 'something'`, it outputs: `Can't access property "child", window.parent is undefined`

Is there any possibility to assign the child without having to assign its parent? Of course, I could assign something that I would never use, but I would like it to be nothing.

Comment: Would `window.parent = { child: 'something' }` not work in this scenario?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/build? What do you expect `window.parent` to be?

Comment: @Thomas, exactly **NOTHING**. In the best case, I would like to skip the assignation.

Comment: @thanatonian2311, that's exactly what I wanted to do,but the nesting is a bit ugly. Can't I just somehow assign `null` to the parent?

Comment: You mean like: `I want to put something in a box! But I don't have a box, and I don't want to use a box. Why do I need a box for that?` I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, I want to put something inside a box without having to assign a value to it (like material, size, shape). Only an unspecified box. Just like thanatonina2311 did.